# Why can't i run my xcode project in simulator in 12+?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

as the title suggests, i cant run my (objective c) project in xcode after upgrading to Xcode 12. It is a Cocoapods project.

It works fine when i deploy to my phone, but in the simulator
I get three different errors for some reason.

1. It complains about "missing module file" for a separate project i include:
   **module map file '...(path)/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myProject/myProject.imagemap' not found**
2. It complains about a precompiled header:
   **:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '(path)/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/myProject-Bridging-Header-swift_2UGSYUUFRK85M-clang_18QKMU0TXX4JD.pch' for bridging header '(path)/iphone/myProject/myProject-Bridging-Header.h'**
3. Finally it complains about Not finding a bundle for a library that i use:
   **error: Resource "(path)/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FCAlertView/FCAlertView.bundle" not found. Run 'pod install' to update the copy resources script.**

I am not super knowledgeable about xcode inner workings, so if anyone has any pointers, i'd be most grateful.

Comment: For the last one: "Run 'pod install' to update the copy resources script.", did you do that? Also, some cache issue might be the problem, so remove derived data?

Comment: Thanks but i did that. Again, it works when i deploy to a real phone. If i had not run pod install, i don't think it would run on the phone either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who get here because of a similar issue:

My issue turned out to be that for the "VALID_ARCHS" setting, found in
"Project, Build Settings, User-Defined" was missing the one needed to run on a simulator, "x86_64".

For some reason, it had been removed. Once i added it, it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Simulator application
2. Restart Xcode
3. Run the project on sim to start the sim up
4. "Erase content and settings" on the simulator
5. Run again after it rebooted

Comment: Thanks, but how would i run the project on simulator when it doesn't even build? That is the problem, it builds when i have the target as my real phone, but if i change the target to any simulator i get the errors when i try to build. Also, i have tried deploying to a simulator i have never used before, no difference.

Comment: 3. Is only to boot the sim. Try the above and come back with error in case it still fails.

Comment: I've tried this, did not help. Again, the simulators are "clean" since i just installed them. My project doesn't even get to the simulator stage, since it fails when building